# How to mark past bars?

Tags: pine-script

It seems that there is a way to write an indicator that is marking bars in the past. I am testing conditions over a continuous range of bars going forward in time and once fulfilled I would like to mark the entire range of bars. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly you want to mark them?
There is different approaches to do it, for navigation in bars use `bar_index`, and `barstate` functions.

For example, pritning label `"Condition"` ten bars before realtime:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

print_info(string_info, bar_n) =>
    var l1 = label.new(na, na)
    label.set_xy(l1, bar_n, high)
    label.set_text(l1, string_info)
    

if barstate.isrealtime
    bar  = bar_index - 10 // some condition
    print_info("Condition", bar)


plot(close)
```

Also you can fill some areas with bars that you need. Use this like a reference:
https://kodify.net/tradingview/background/area-plot-background/